# SQLite3 and releasing of locks

Tags: c++, windows, sqlite, locking

SQLite has different levels of locks: `UNLOCKED`, `SHARED`, `RESERVED`, `PENDING`, `EXCLUSIVE`.

I can't find information which calls to SQLite API acquire and release that locks.

As I understand lock acquired when `sqlite3_step` called. Type of lock depends on expression of prepared statement. Also this command can escalate lock in write operations inside a custom transaction.

As I understand write lock released also by sqlite3_step - this func returns `SQLITE_DONE` or the error code. I didn't find any docs but seems reasonable that this function should release `RESERVED`/`PENDING`/`EXCLUSIVE` at the end of execution.

But I do not understand what happens with read operations. 
To get all queried rows we need to call `sqlite3_step` several times - each call gives us one row.

I found SQLite docs about OS cache and citation from Unlock-notify API: `it is not possible for one call to sqlite3_step() to return SQLITE_ROW and then the next SQLITE_LOCKED`

I assume that in read operations first call to `sqlite3_step` acquires `SHARED` lock and loads data from the file to OS cache. Lock released if `sqlite3_step` returned anything except `SQLITE_ROW` (i.e. `SQLITE_DONE` or error code).

Is it right?

How we can manually release acquired lock for read operation? `sqlite3_reset`?

Comment: Read the documentation about [locking](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) and [transactions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQLite acquires lock on database/table in `sqlite3_prepare` and releases it in `sqlite3_finalize`.
Type of lock depends on your SQL expression.

Therefore if you created an STMT - you need to execute it and finalize as soon as possible. Otherwise you block different connections.

Example: 
If you created STMT for an `SELECT` expression - you acquired `SHARED` lock. Therefore all write operations from different connections are blocked until STMT finalized.

Comment: This is unfortunately wrong. The locks aren't acquired in `sqlite3_prepare`. And you can use `sqlite3_reset` to release the locks (*A statement finishes when its prepared statement is reset or finalized.* - https://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), so you don't need to `sqlite3_finalize` ASAP.